# selenium open multiple links

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium

I am having a list of links:

```
links=[link1,link2,link3]
```

I open every link and search for some info and then i save some data to another list:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
 for link in links:
  browser.get(link)
  for data in browser.find_elements_by_xpath(//....):
   database.append(data.text)
```

But this proccess takes ages, so i am trying to speed it.
I am trying to open as many browsers as links i have, and do the same process simultaneously.

```
for i in range(len(links)):
 #then open browsers and save data from all sites to same list simultaneously
```

The problem is:
I dont know how to open as many browsers as links i have, and do the same process(save data to the same list) simultaneously.

Comment: You didn't say what the problem is, so it's not that easy to help

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for the job. If you need speed to scrape data look at Scrapy (python based)